# Powershell if statements not executing

Tags: variables, powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the follow snippet a powershell script and the nested if statements are not being executed.  Can you tell me why ?  I've recently got back into the programming game so its probably something simple

```
$false. 
$IgnoreThisLine = $false
$tmpString = "(DATUM CTR OF BLADE)"
$EndOfDescription = $null 
$cncPrograms ="(165756 SIDE 1)"

if ($IgnoreThisLine = $false ) {
    If ($tmpString -match '\(') {
        $EndOfDescription =  $false
        $cncPrograms = $tmpString 
        }
    else {
    $EndOfDescription = $true               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($IgnoreThisLine -eq $false)
```

"-eq" not "=" to test for equality with PowerShell.

Comment: +1 - OP should know that his `IF` block there is really just reassigning the `$ignorethisline` variable to `$false`, and then executing based on if that assignment succeeded

Comment: For booleans you don't even need to do that.  If (-not $IgnorethisLine) is the same as testing if it equals false. If you wanted to test if a value is true: If ($IgnoreThisLine) {"I am true"} else {"I am false"}